# Loop over files in different directories

Tags: bash, sort, cat

I have a set of text files containing values and stored across several directories. I need to workout a command with loop, so that I can apply my command to each files in several directories.

The code I figured is

```
#!/bin/bash
#
dir=`pwd`
datapath1=$dir/datafiles1
datapath2-$dir/datafiles2

for file in /$datapath1/*.txt ; do 
   sort -k1,1rn < "$file"
done > file.cat &&
# 
for file in /$datapath2/*.txt ; do 
   sort -k1,1rn < "$file"
done > file.cat &&
#
```

clearly, this is very difficult in the case of many directories.
Is there any simplified approach for this, possibly accommodate in a single loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your script: Each loop overwrites `file.cat`.

The problem can be eliminated and the script simplified if you loop
over all files in a single loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$(pwd)
datapath1=$dir/datafiles1
datapath2=$dir/datafiles2

for file in "$datapath1"/*.txt "$datapath2"/*.txt; do 
   sort -k1,1rn < "$file"
done > file.cat
```

Also always quote your variables.

---

As noted by Kusalananda, if the directory names are very similar, it may be even possible to use a glob that addresses all directories and files involved. In the example given, that is indeed possible with

```
sort -k1,1rn "$PWD"/datafiles[12]/*.txt > file.cat
```

Comment: Thanks, the quotes around the variable in the for loop and leaving the *.txt out of the quotes did the trick for me!